# How to Uninstall The Client Services for NetWare (CSNW) in XP?

Tags: service, windows-xp

I tried to use the steps to uninstall **The Client Services for NetWare (CSNW)**, but it didn't appear in the properties Network Connnection.  The only place I can find it is in the Control Panel named (**CSNW**), but I can't delete it from there.I want to get rid of it so I can use the Welcome Screen.  It doesn't appear to be doing anything else, but keeping the Welcome Screen from working.elso was not removed from Services Microsoft Management Console (**MMC**) and it disabled.

Any help will be appreciated

**My system is xp pro sp3 (old)**